# MatrixXcd incorrect fill small number in Eigen lib

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

When i fill the MatrixXcd, with smaller numbers than 1 ...it fill with zeros...its bug???

```
        for (int j=0; j<w; ++j){ // loop over columns
       for (int i=0; i<h; ++i){ // loop over rows
        //Load_mat(i,j); // to access matrix coefficients,
        int distance=sqrt(((i+1)-p)^2+((j+1)-p)^2);
        blb_filter01.real().coeffRef(i,j)=0.4512651561561651515631;/

                blb_filter01.imag().coeffRef(i,j)=0;

    }

 }
```

Comment: You know that `^` isn't exponentiation but bitwise x-or, right?

Comment: yes, i rewrite this from matlab:) thx,